# I have a error after adding nativescript to an angular project

Tags: angular, nativescript

I had a working angular project, and wanted to try NativeScript, so I added NativeScript to it using `npm install --global @nativescript/schematics` and `ng add @nativescript/schematics` but now when I try to run `ng serve` I get this error

> ERROR in error TS6053: File 'C:[path]/src/src/main.ts' not found.
>
> error TS6053: File 'C:[path]/src/src/polyfills.ts' not found.

I tried deleting node_modlues, and running `npm install` again, but the error is the same. I even tried restarting my terminal and run `ng serve` again and the result is the same

Did I do something wrong? Or did i forget to do something?

***EDIT***

tsconfig.app.json file:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": [
        "src/*.web",
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the keyword 'src/' from the paths mentioned in the files array and try. checkout this - https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-schematics/issues/240
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, both the web and mobile app work now. Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems as a problem with paths or files properties inside `tsconfig.app.json`. Can you paste it here to check if this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix this is to change the location of `main` file inside angular.json -> "main": "src/main.ts"